# Ember not saving records when using DS.RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a new object via the DS.RESTAdapter , but I don't see any activity on the backend (via console or in the db). There's no errors output in the console (using chrome). Reading data via index and show works fine. In my route.rb I have

```
resource @posts, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
```

After I fill out a form and click submit this line gets called (trying static data to start with)

```
this.get('store').createRecord('post', {name: 'asdf'});
```

In the ember inspector in chrome I see under "Data" the new records being created without the ID. I notice the new method in my backend post controller isn't called so is there another step I have to do for the adapter to attempt a REST PUT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createRecord` only creates the record in the store.

To persist that record you need to call `save()` on it.

```
// Puts record into store
var newPost = this.get('store').createRecord('post', {name: 'asdf'});
// Persists it
newPost.save();
```

See: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/